# Java Error when Trying to Run Geomesa Quick Start with Kafka Data Store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, geomesa

I want to discover the GeoMesa technology.

I try to run the Quick Start, on the official website of [GeoMesa](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-kafka.html).

I use Kafka Data sore, installed by a docker-compose (the ports `9092` for Kafka brokers, `9000` for Kafka manager and `2181` for Zookeeper server), and the version `2.4.0-SNAPSHOT` of GeoMesa.

Like it is written on the tutorial of [GeoMesa](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-kafka.html), I run the followed command lines :

Get the tutorial from the GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/geomesa/geomesa-tutorials.git
cd geomesa-tutorials
```

Compile with Maven:

```
mvn clean install -pl geomesa-tutorials-kafka/geomesa-tutorials-kafka-quickstart -am
```

Run the application with the adresses `localhost:9092` for Kafka broker and `localhost:2181` for Zookeeper server:

```
java -cp geomesa-tutorials-kafka/geomesa-tutorials-kafka-quickstart/target/geomesa-tutorials-kafka-quickstart-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.geomesa.example.kafka.KafkaQuickStart --kafka.brokers localhost:9092 --kafka.zookeepers localhost:2181
```

When I run the last command line, an error is thrown on my console :

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Method org.locationtech.geomesa.security.AuthorizationsProvider.apply(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/locationtech/geomesa/security/AuthorizationsProvider; must be InterfaceMethodref constant
>       at org.locationtech.geomesa.security.package$.getAuthorizationsProvider(package.scala:57)
>       at org.locationtech.geomesa.kafka.data.KafkaDataStoreFactory$.buildAuthProvider(KafkaDataStoreFactory.scala:194)
>       at org.locationtech.geomesa.kafka.data.KafkaDataStoreFactory$.buildConfig(KafkaDataStoreFactory.scala:175)
>       at org.locationtech.geomesa.kafka.data.KafkaDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(KafkaDataStoreFactory.scala:46)
>       at org.locationtech.geomesa.kafka.data.KafkaDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(KafkaDataStoreFactory.scala:37)
>       at org.geotools.data.DataAccessFinder.getDataStore(DataAccessFinder.java:121)
>       at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(DataStoreFinder.java:71)
>       at org.geomesa.example.quickstart.GeoMesaQuickStart.createDataStore(GeoMesaQuickStart.java:105)
>       at org.geomesa.example.kafka.KafkaQuickStart.createDataStore(KafkaQuickStart.java:68)
>       at org.geomesa.example.quickstart.GeoMesaQuickStart.run(GeoMesaQuickStart.java:79)
>       at org.geomesa.example.kafka.KafkaQuickStart.main(KafkaQuickStart.java:133)

I suspect the error comes from this method `org.geomesa.example.quickstart.GeoMesaQuickStart.createDataStore`.

I try the same Quick Start with a Redis server, installed by a Docker image, and I get exactly the same error.

Comment: Make sure you are using Java 8, as listed in those docs

Comment: The command line `java --version' gives me this output : `openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15`. Is it a problem that I don't have the Java 8 version ? Must I go back to Java 8 ?

Comment: I run with Java 8 version, and it works. It was just a problem of Java version. Unfortunately, GeoMesa does not work with Java 11 version

Answer (score 1):

> The command line java --version' gives me this output : openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15. Is it a problem that I don't have the Java 8 version ?

According to the documentation you linked to, one of the prerequisites is to use Java 8 to run GeoMesa.